# What to put in library path in Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi

Which folders should I put in the library path in the Delphi IDE ? Only the ones containing .dcu ? I had problems when I updated some libraries.

**EDIT**

What I want to achieve is to avoid the *error F2051 Unit xxxxx was compiled with a different version of yyyyy* when I update libraries.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: This error indicates what you didn't rebuilt the library.

Comment: You asked a broad and largely unanswerable question about global library path. Now you mention a compilation error. Which is it to be? If the latter, show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule:

The **Library Path** setting in the IDE should contain paths referenced by all/most or many of your projects.  This will almost certainly include the paths to **source** of any package libraries installed in the IDE (that is, components installed into your IDE component library).

Any libraries that are used only by certain projects should be included in the **Search Path** setting for those specific projects.

You should only need to include the path to any `dcu`'s for libraries *for which you do not have the source*.  But whether you add the path to the IDE or to a project settings is independent of whether that path is to source or dcu files.

As noted right at the start however, this is only a very *general* rule of thumb.  Your specific needs may be different in a way that is not possible to determine from the question in its current very general form.